# pagination control not showing page number links

Tags: angularjs

pagination-control not showing direction arrows when items Per Page is expression, I have install angular-utils-pagination using bower add dependencies in controller. please tell me what to do..

Comment: show your code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the controls are added on the `dirPagination.tpl.html` as following:

```
<ul class="pagination" ng-if="1 < pages.length || !autoHide">
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }">
        <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(1)">&laquo;</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == 1 }">
        <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current - 1)">&lsaquo;</a>
    </li>

    .... repeat items here ....

    <li ng-if="directionLinks" ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }">
        <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)">&rsaquo;</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="boundaryLinks"  ng-class="{ disabled : pagination.current == pagination.last }">
        <a href="" ng-click="setCurrent(pagination.last)">&raquo;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also make sure the `direction-links` are set to `true`(default) on the `dir-pagination-controls` directive.

> direction-links (optional, default = true) Specify whether to display
>   the "forwards" & "backwards" arrows in the pagination.

If the problem still remains, please share some more code trough a Punkr/Fiddle/... Se we can have a better insight.